# How to add to google play console internal test staging and production builds?

Tags: android, build.gradle, google-play-console

Is it possible to add two builds to the google play console internal test so they are available for installation?
I need it to test the staging and production builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one track in Internal testing, but you can have multiple tracks in closed testing.

In closed testing, you can click "Create track" to add the tracks for your different builds.

Therefore, in your case, you could use:

- Internal Test track for your staging builds
- Closed testing to test your production versions

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user14678216!
I've done what you said, but at play market, there is only one version(latest) available for installation. Is it possible somehow to instal previous one?

Comment: If you want to change testing tracks then you will have to send the invite again form the other channel the change the user's channel and then you will have access to the other app version